# Docker: E: Unable to locate package mysql-client —-no-install-recommends

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I'm following this tutorial: [Laravel 5.6 in Docker with PHP 7.2, NGINX 1.10 and MySQL 5.7](https://medium.com/@phillipmarkpadilla/laravel-5-6-in-docker-with-php-7-2-nginx-1-10-and-mysql-5-7-cdb6c054379c)

Which is basically an update of this: [Laravel + Docker Part 1 — setup for Development](https://medium.com/@shakyShane/laravel-docker-part-1-setup-for-development-e3daaefaf3c)

But when I ran

```
docker-compose up
```

I got this error

```
E: Unable to locate package mysql-client —-no-install-recommends
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-client —-no-install-recommends  && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

A full output

```
Creating network "pulzu_default" with the default driver
Building app
Step 1/2 : FROM php:7.2.2-fpm
 ---> 60245f64ed12
Step 2/2 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-client —-no-install-recommends  && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
 ---> Running in cefd70564b31
Get:1 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
Ign:2 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Get:3 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]
Get:5 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [468 kB]
Get:4 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release [118 kB]
Get:6 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg [2434 B]
Get:7 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages [12.1 kB]
Get:8 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages [9530 kB]
Fetched 10.3 MB in 2s (4142 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package mysql-client —-no-install-recommends
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-client —-no-install-recommends  && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You have a syntax error in `mysql-client —-no-install-recommends` because you copied the code from the article. The option must be with this symbol `--`. Try this `mysql-client  --no-install-recommends`

Answer (score 5):

The image is missing dependencies to be able to install `mysql-client`, this is caused by the `--no-install-recommends` flag. By default, Ubuntu installs recommended but not suggested packages. With `--no-install-recommends`, only the main dependencies (packages in the Depends field) are installed.

Change the `Dockerfile` or according to the article `app.dockerfile` to:

`FROM php:7.2.2-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
 && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql`

And you should be able to build the image, therefore the `docker-compose up` command would work.

Comment: Great! Also I advise you to always read the `Dockerfile` files, most of the time they are running commands to install libraries, dependencies, services, etc, just as you would do in a not containerized environment (Unix based).